# one error in this website i made

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

This is the website i made [www.quickfix.me](http://www.quickfix.me). When i see in the mobile site i can see some alignments are wrong place. Help me with that.

I have tried to find but i cant find it.

**For example**.

In the services menu see one service, for example **computer**. Problem is, its not aligned well please help me with that.

[image]

Comment: You're going to have to post some code to get decent help here..

Comment: how bro its a very big css code

Answer (score 1):

remove `position: absolute;` from `.breadcrumb` after `@media (max-width: 767px)` .

for example

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .breadcrumb {
    position: static;
  }
}
```

Comment: change absolute to static?

Comment: see your .breadcrumb its default on absolute so change it in mobile

Comment: can you pleas tell me how i need to enlarge the logo i tried by resizing the logo but it desplaying only half of the logo any idea of that?

Comment: on image i jsut resized the image can you pleas tell me how i can change the size of that?

Comment: There is lots of images there